# Default push viewController animation doesn't play

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a floating bug in my application.
Sometimes, when I make

```
rootNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
```

the animation doesn't work. New viewController is created, and the method `viewWillAppear` is called, but UI doesn't change. New viewController is outside the screen.

I use swizzling to connect to `CALayer.add(_:forKey:)`.
This is a stack trace for animation without problem:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x00000001030ae890 in CALayer.swizz_add(_:forKey:)
#1  0x00000001030af468 in @objc CALayer.swizz_add(_:forKey:) ()
#2  0x000000018af12708 in -[UIViewAnimationState _trackAnimation:nonAdditiveAnimation:withAnimationKey:forKeyPath:inLayer:] ()
#3  0x000000018ba5dbe0 in __85+[UIViewPropertyAnimator _animationBlockForTrackingAnimation:animator:trackingSetup:]_block_invoke ()
#4  0x000000018afaa224 in -[UIViewPropertyAnimator _runAnimations] ()
#5  0x000000018ba64484 in __49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#6  0x000000018ba642d4 in __49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke ()
#7  0x000000018ba643f8 in __49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke.1052 ()
#8  0x000000018afa9cbc in -[UIViewPropertyAnimator _setupAnimationTracking:] ()
#9  0x000000018afa96d4 in -[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:] ()
#10 0x000000018afa79b4 in +[UIViewPropertyAnimator _trackAnimationWithAnimator:forLayer:forAnimationKey:trackingSetup:] ()
#11 0x000000018b00ea90 in +[UIViewPropertyAnimator _trackAdditiveAnimationWithAnimator:nonAdditiveAnimation:withAnimationKey:forKeyPath:forLayer:] ()
#12 0x000000018b1e0534 in __67-[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:]_block_invoke.170 ()
#13 0x000000018aeab20c in -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] ()
#14 0x0000000185338c24 in CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) ()
#15 0x000000018532aa24 in -[CALayer setPosition:] ()
#16 0x000000018532afd4 in -[CALayer setFrame:] ()
.....
```

And here stack trace when I face bug:

```
#0  0x000000010488a554 in CALayer.swizz_add(_:forKey:)
#1  0x000000010488aefc in @objc CALayer.swizz_add(_:forKey:) ()
#2  0x000000018b1fb0ec in __modifyTrackedAnimationsWithFactory_block_invoke ()
#3  0x000000018b1ebdc4 in mapTrackedAnimations ()
#4  0x000000018b1ebb40 in +[UIView modifyTrackedAnimations:removeOnCompletion:animationFactory:block:] ()
#5  0x000000018ba5fe00 in -[UIViewPropertyAnimator _pauseAnimation:] ()
#6  0x000000018ba61080 in -[UIViewPropertyAnimator pauseAnimation] ()
#7  0x000000018afa79d8 in +[UIViewPropertyAnimator _trackAnimationWithAnimator:forLayer:forAnimationKey:trackingSetup:] ()
#8  0x000000018b00ea90 in +[UIViewPropertyAnimator _trackAdditiveAnimationWithAnimator:nonAdditiveAnimation:withAnimationKey:forKeyPath:forLayer:] ()
#9  0x000000018b1e0534 in __67-[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:]_block_invoke.170 ()
#10 0x000000018aeab20c in -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] ()
#11 0x0000000185338c24 in CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) ()
#12 0x000000018532aa24 in -[CALayer setPosition:] ()
#13 0x000000018532afd4 in -[CALayer setFrame:] ()
....
```

In the second case `pauseAnimation` is called insted of `startAnimationAsPaused:`, and animations are added for keys `"UIPacingAnimationForAnimatorsKey"`, `"position"` with speed = 0. Where could i make a mistake?
It is a bug on devices and in simulators.
I don't use custom transitions.

Comment: Do you call pushViewController always on the main thread?

Comment: Yes. I call pushViewController always on the main thread, in the collectionViewDelegate method "didSelectItemAtIndex"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have something incorrectly implemented when you do swizzling. Try to disable it and check if `startAnimationAsPaused` is being called. If it works as expected, then go deeper in the swizzling stuff (would be good to see your code) and check what's going on there.